# The value of variable in JavaScript and jQuery doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

Why doesn't the value of variable show? I think it should be 1 or 0 depending on value inside of variable `bayar`, but why its doesn't work

I've tried to do anything that I can do but it doesn't work like it try to change several code but it doesn't work.

Here's my controller code:

```
 public function generated(){
 $data=DB::table("tb_trx_perhitungan_bunga_simpanan")
        ->selectRaw('trx_bulan')
        ->get();  

  return view('crud.form.cobaNampilin',compact('data'));
 }
```

And here's my JavaScript and jQuery code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var a;
            var array = {!! json_encode($data) !!};
            var i;
            var b;
            $('#bulan').keyup(function(){
            var bayar=parseInt($('#bulan').val());
                for(i=0;i<=array.length;i++){
                    if(bayar==array[i].trx_bulan){
                        a=1;
                    }
                    else{
                        a=0;
                    }
                }

             $('#hasil').val(a);
            });
        });
        </script>
```

I expected the output is 1 or 0

The content of var `array` I think should be `[trx_bulan 1],[trx_bulan 2],[trx_bulan 3],[trx_bulan 4],[trx_bulan 5],[trx_bulan 6]` because content of `array` is an array object. I read that on the website so that's why I use `array[index].trx_bulan]` to call the value of each index.

Here's the screenshot of table data:

[image: heres the screenshot of table data]

Comment: i just updated it

Comment: I think it should be [trx_bulan 1],[trx_bulan 2],[trx_bulan 3],[trx_bulan 4],[trx_bulan 5],[trx_bulan 6]

Comment: what happens when you `console.log(array)`?

Comment: it doest show anything if im using console so tried to use $('#hasil').val(array);       and the output like this
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @bramastavikana an array cannot be an object in JavaScript. You can have an array of objects or an array of arrays. So `var array = [ "item 1", "item 2" ];` is valid or `var array = [{ "index 1": "item 1"}, {"index 1": "item 2"}];` Also did you mean `json_decode()`??

Comment: but array[i].trx_bulan work if im not using if else code  and how to convert array of an object to array of char like u said? ,  i browse in the internet that json_decode convert array of an object to array of char but it doesn't work still object and it doesn't effect the code so i didnot ererase it @Twisty

Comment: @bramastavikana we will need to see a sample of the `$data`

Comment: i updated it @Twisty

Comment: I tried  change json_encode to json_decode but error appear, it says Array to string conversion error message @Twisty

Comment: @bramastavikana I don't use laravel much, so I misunderstood the usage. I looked it up and included the correct method in my answer for you: `var data = {{json_encode($data)}};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you have a data table like:

[image: Table Data]

Then consider the following code:

```js
$(function() {
  var a = 0;

  /*
  In laravel use:

  var data = {{json_encode($data)}};

  it will translate to something like:
  */
  var data = [{
    id: 27,
    trx_bulan: 1,
    trx_tahun: 2018,
    tangal_proses: "2018-12-09 07:23:00",
    persentase_bunga: 0.2,
    id_user: 3
  }, {
    id: 28,
    trx_bulan: 2,
    trx_tahun: 2018,
    tangal_proses: "2018-12-09 03:42:39",
    persentase_bunga: 0.2,
    id_user: 3
  }, {
    id: 29,
    trx_bulan: 3,
    trx_tahun: 2018,
    tangal_proses: "2018-12-09 03:43:43",
    persentase_bunga: 0.2,
    id_user: 3
  }, {
    id: 30,
    trx_bulan: 4,
    trx_tahun: 2018,
    tangal_proses: "2018-12-09 03:44:06",
    persentase_bunga: 0.2,
    id_user: 3
  }, {
    id: 31,
    trx_bulan: 5,
    trx_tahun: 2018,
    tangal_proses: "2018-12-09 03:45:40",
    persentase_bunga: 0.2,
    id_user: 3
  }, {
    id: 33,
    trx_bulan: 6,
    trx_tahun: 2018,
    tangal_proses: "2018-12-09 06:32:38",
    persentase_bunga: 0.2,
    id_user: 3
  }];

  $('#bulan').keyup(function(e) {
    var bayar = parseInt($('#bulan').val());
    a = 0;
    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
      if (bayar == v.trx_bulan) {
        console.log("Hit", v);
        a = 1;
      }
    });
    $('#hasil').val(a);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="bulan" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="hasil" />
```

You may want to consider switching to `type="number"` or checking that the entry is a number value when the user types something.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It never return output because wrong loop condition, the loop `for(i=0;i<=array.length;i++)` will throw error and `$('#hasil').val(a);` will not executed.

> TypeError: array[i] is undefined

It is because `i` index is out of range, use the `<` only

```
for(i=0; i<array.length; i++)
```

then if element with ID `hasil` is not `<input>` use `.html()`

```
$('#hasil').html(a);
```

And there are several ways to convert to JSON

- `@json` Blade directive

  ```
   var array = @json($data);
  ```
- single Curly brackets

  ```
  var array = {!! json_encode($data) !!};
  ```
- using `toJson()`

  ```
  var array = {!! $data->toJson() !!};
  ```
- and native php

  ```
  var array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
  ```

Comment: gpp ga usah, tanda centangnya juga di ilangin yah :(